# Break WHERE IN into multiple SELECTS

Tags: sql

Does it make it *perform* better overall to break [this](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/16821294/WhereOBJECTIDIN122072Items) WHERE IN into many selects e.g

```
SELECT aField FROM aTable WHERE objectId IN (0,1,2...999) * many
```

Compared to having a huge WHERE objectId IN (700k items).

Edit---

The list of objectIds I have in memory and it can be as many as 700k items. They can be continuous but very unlikely.
It is also not determinant whether the field in the where clause (objectId in this case) is indexed or not.

The third party application that allows me to pass only a WHERE CLAUSE is currently using an Oracle DB. It also has options to connect to other types of DBs but the user base of the plugin I'm developing works mostly against an Oracle DB.

Comment: Where are you getting the objectid's from? Another query?

Comment: If this numbers are continuous, `BETWEEN` may also be a solution for you.

Comment: I've editted the question to answer the comments @JoachimIsaksson and Blausocke

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Oracle DB @Quassnoi, but I do not have access to do anything to the sql apart from altering the WHERE CLAUSE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As many as 700k items? If that's the case I'd seriously consider storing these in a separate table and using a `JOIN` instead - that would perform much better if objectId is an indexed foreign key.

Comment: Sorry just edited the question. The third party app only allows me access to the WHERE CLAUSE, it constructs the entire sql statement and I do not have control on this thus far.

Comment: Oh, in that case I'd go with @Blauesocke's suggestion of slimming the clause down by using BETWEEN (or <=, >=) wherever there are contiguous blocks of ID's.

Comment: I could look into ordering them into contiguous blocks of ID's but it seems that my options are _very_ limited as long as I only have access to the WHERE clause.

Comment: Yes it sounds like the options are very limited if you can't do a join. With that many items you'll have an extremely long SQL statement whatever you do (and may possibly breach a limit of what can be parsed by the SQL interpreter?) Sorry I can't help further...

Answer (score 1):

Its better to read but harder to debug, internally it would be interesting which one is faster, usually I would say the option with the list of ObjectIDs, but to transfer such a huge amount of data costs some performance too, you can compare both variants using an Explain plan depending on our DBMS.